# How can I generate a unique channel name for 2 users in a socket based IM?

Tags: socket.io, twilio, discrete-mathematics

Each pair of users needs a unique string to represent their conversation. Each user has a unique id, so my current plan is to:

1. Sort the user ids alphabetically
       e.g `userB, userA` -> `['userA', 'userB']`
2. Then concatenate the two names with some character
       e.g. `'userA::userB'`

Seems a bit hackish and I'm not entirely convinced this will result in unique strings. I can't seem to work out a proof either way.

Is there a recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is hacky. The combination of 2 unique keys, the usernames, will form a third unique key that unambiguously connects the two users.

This is analagous to a compound primary key in a database that uses two ids from different entities to uniquely key a relationship between them.

The only thing that keeps bugging me about this is whether messing with the concatenating character could cause a clash. I think this is avoided by your alphabetising, but if you had users "UserA:", "UserA", ":UserB" and "UserB" then you may clash with "UserA:::UserB". To avoid this outright, make sure you concatenate using a character that cannot appear within usernames.